# Cannot access window properties when running tests with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to access a property that is located under `window.sunpietro.config` property. When running tests with Jest I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`.

My test code looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup } from 'react-testing-library';
import MyModule from '../my.module';
import { myConfigMock } from '../../../../jest.window.mock';

afterEach(cleanup);
beforeEach(() => {
    window.sunpietro = { ...myConfigMock };

    // window.sunpietro.config = {};
});

describe('MyModule', () => {
    test('The module renders correctly', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<MyModule />);

        getByTestId('my-tabs').toBeDefined();
        getByTestId('my-panels').toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I'm using the latest version of Jest: `24.7.1` and the `react-testing-library` version: `6.1.2`.

How can I mock the `window` properties so they're accessible by `MyModule` instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set global variables in your setup. I have this setupFiles declared in my package.json

```
"jest": {
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/tests/shim.js",
  ...
],
```

Then in my shim.js. I am declaring window properties as global like

```
global.sunpietro : {
 ...
}
```